# How to obtain public key from Openstack using Terraform and save it locally?

Tags: openstack, terraform, terraform-provider-openstack

I'm trying to obtain a public key from Openstack (to later save it on local machine) using data source `openstack_compute_keypair_v2` in Terraform:

```
data "openstack_compute_keypair_v2" "app_public_key" {
    name = "app-key"
}
```

, but when I run `terraform apply` nothing happens. (The key exists and the name is also correct.)

I assumed (maybe wrong) that I need to save them manually so I used `local_file` resource.

```
resource "local_file" "app_cert" {
    content = "${openstack_compute_keypair_v2.app_public_key.public_key}"
    filename = "${path.module}/app.cert"
}
```

But I am getting:
`Error: resource 'local_file.app_cert' config: unknown resource 'openstack_compute_keypair_v2.app_public_key' referenced in variable openstack_compute_keypair_v2.app_public_key.public_key`

According to the [documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/openstack/d/compute_keypair_v2.html) there is such attribute. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So near.
That second bit is just missing data.
So it should be:

```
resource "local_file" "app_cert" {
    content = "${data.openstack_compute_keypair_v2.app_public_key.public_key}"
    filename = "${path.module}/app.cert"
}
```